# Use python to modify file (workaround for WindowsError 5 Access is denied)

Tags: python

I am trying to augment `C:\program files\%X%\%text_file%.txt` .

I am admin on my PC and granted full access to all users on this text file (overkill, but its a local PC).

I am trying to use [the solution documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829043/how-to-remove-read-only-attrib-directory-with-python-in-windows), yet I am still getting `WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied`.

My goal would be to have a script that systematically can go in and modify the text file. My current python code matches that in the link above directly.

Thank you for any guidance!!

Answer (score 0):

Without sample code to demonstrate the usage, I can only presume that you are using "C:\program files\%X%\%text_file%.txt" directly and there are no valid environment variables for "X" and "text_file" for it to replace with.

On Windows, a value wrapped in % is expanded and replaced with an environment variable.
For example `echo %TEMP%` at the Command Prompt (CMD.EXE) will expand out the `TEMP` environment variable and print out something like `C:\Program Files\Temp`

I hope this helps