# Deleting the whole folder with no "Access Denied" error

Tags: python, windows, winapi, shutil

I'm trying to run a script (with admin privileges) that deletes a specific directory (using `shutil.rmtree`). Now, some of its files raises the following error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

When I delete it using *Windows Explorer*, it succeeds with no errors.

How can I delete the whole folder using `shutil.rmtree` without the errors?

I found out that I can use `win32api.SetFileAttributes(filepath, win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL)` to a specific file which fixes the error issue.

Is there a way to do it for the whole folder, or is there another way to delete the whole folder with no errors that I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you narrow down which file is causing the issue? Then you can inspect its properties in Explorer to see which attribute is the cause of this error. My money is on `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY`. If that is indeed the case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829043/how-to-remove-read-only-attrib-directory-with-python-in-windows

Comment: @Thomas yes.. It seems that this was the problem. Thanks!!

Comment: @Thomas Yeah.. it seems to be a duplicate.. I don't know how I didn't find this question earlier