# Is there one python function that removes files AND directories indiscriminately?

Tags: python

As far I can tell, there are separate APIs to remove folders and files in Python (`os.remove` and `os.rmdir` or `shutil.rmtree`).  Isn't there one function library that does it all, no question asked, or do I need to write my own function to do so?

In short, what is the python equivalent of `rm -fr` ?

Comment: `shutil.rmtree` does `rm -fr`

Comment: So, in short python equivalent of `rm -fr` is `shutil.rmtree`

Comment: But why do you want function library other than  `shutil.rmtree`

Comment: @PCM just tested it and rmtree returns: ´NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'test'´

Comment: of course, you need to put something like `C:/...` not test

Comment: As far as i know there is no function that does that but you could easily write one and use it in your code.

Comment: >touch xxx.x
>python
Python 3.7.9 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.rmtree("xxx.x")
...NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'xxx.x'
>>> exit()

Comment: So you want to remove files and folders using your cmd prompt or terminal ?

Comment: @Kerrim Yes, that's what I have for now. Just did not want to reinvent the wheel and would rather make sure I am not missing a library. Seems odd not to have that support natively.

Comment: @PCM No, I simply showed using my terminal that rmtree doesn't work on files. I am asking if in a python script I can use a library function that will remove directories and files the same way.

Comment: No, you can't but you can mix 2 func to remove files and folders

Comment: Have you heard about `os.unlink(path)`

Comment: What is the use case where you do not know if your target is a directory or a file? You should know

Comment: There doesn't exist such a function in python, linux rm -rf removes all files even if it has read-only permission. but shutil.rmtree doesn't do that see this answer <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829043/how-to-remove-read-only-attrib-directory-with-python-in-windows>

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41789397/11647025

Comment: @crissal The answer you point me to is essentially the function I wrote. I was wondering if I could avoid having a custom function do just that. Apparently not. Thank you.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I know if what I want to remove is a file or directory. I have a long list of files and directories and was just hoping to deal with them the same way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a file or folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder)