# Python: remove read-only access Windows to copy and paste files

Tags: python, windows, readonly

I have tried many methods, some from [How to remove read-only attrib directory with Python in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829043/how-to-remove-read-only-attrib-directory-with-python-in-windows) but none work. Still getting the WinError Access Denied message. Simply need to access a file location, remove it, then put a different file in that folder.

Comment: Please share the method you were most confident should work and show what you tried.

Comment: If the user account that your script is running as doesn't have access to some location, there's really no way to get around that (it'd be a serious security problem if there was), so you'd want to make sure it is just a file permissions issue, and that the account your script is running as actually has the rights to make the changes you're looking to make.

Comment: @Grismar I tried the methods on the link, but thought this one would work

import os, shutil, stat
path = fldr + "/file.txt"
def on_rm_error(func, path, exc_info):
    # path contains the path of the file that couldn't be removed
    # let's just assume that it's read-only and unlink it.
    os.chmod(path, stat.S_IWRITE )
    os.unlink(path)

shutil.rmtree(temp_fldr_at, onerror = on_rm_error )

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is using OS library and execute commands in shell, but in big projects, especially commercial ones, It's going to be a security bug =)
to use it, just import the OS library and use it like `os.system('command')`.

This function let you run any commands in most Operating Systems
In your case, the command for changing the attribute of any file in windows would be `"attrib -\+switch"`

so you can run it like this:

```
import os
file_address = ""
os.system(f'attrib -r "{file_address}"')
```

Comment: It still says "path not found" when I put in the file_address, but the file is there...

Comment: you can use the same command to give the "cd" command and change the directory to the destination path and after that try to delete it.

Comment: Sorry, very new to Python...how do I do the cd command?